# android: TimePickerDialog updating the total minutes

Tags: android, android-edittext, timepickerdialog

first `EditText` show current device time when click on button it show `TimePickerDialog` and i set the new time .

Can we add this new hour and minute to previous .for example current device time is 12:00 and using `TimePickerDialog` update *1:20* then click Ok then show total  *80 Minutes* .My total minutes is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Paste your entire code here

Comment: why you increase/decrease time picked by 12?

Comment: problem is solved thanks.